# Plotting a well defined function displays nothing for two-thirds of the range required

Tags: plotting

The plot in question concerns the second derivative of an inverse Laplace transform (ILT) of  a function with five parameters. Here is the ILT

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
prod = (s - cr1) (s - cr2) (s - cr3) (s - cr4);
LW = (1 + s)^2/(si prod);
Print["symbolic W'=", Wp = D[InverseLaplaceTransform[LW, s, x], x]]
```

Four  parameters are functions of the fifth parameter "si", defined as the roots of a fourth order equation

```
cr = {cr1, cr2, cr3, cr4} = 
   s /. Solve[si s^2 + 107 s/5 + 10 ((1 + s)^(-2) - 1) - 1/10 == 0, 
     s];
```

Plotting the first derivative of the ILT  takes .64

```
lx = 13; Timing[
 pd = Plot[Evaluate[Wp /. si -> 1], {x, 0, lx}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, lx}, {0.0225, .0275}}]]
```

Plotting of the second derivative of the ILT  takes 14.84 and displays nothing for two-thirds of the range lx

```
    Wd = D[Wp, x];
Timing[Plot[(Wd /. si -> 1), {x, 0, lx}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, lx}, {-0.002, .002}}]]
```

Comment: There are tiny complex parts. Try plotting `Chop[(Wd /. si -> 1)]` instead to remove these and it works. Using Re would also be reasonable because the imaginary parts are extremely small.

Comment: Thanks, Obviously !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]
prod = (s - cr1) (s - cr2) (s - cr3) (s - cr4);
LW = (1 + s)^2/(si prod);
Print["symbolic W'=", 
 Wp = D[InverseLaplaceTransform[LW, s, x], x] // Simplify]
```

[image]

```
cr = {cr1, cr2, cr3, cr4} = 
   s /. Solve[si s^2 + 107 s/5 + 10 ((1 + s)^(-2) - 1) - 1/10 == 0, s];
```

Prior to plotting, simplify the function using [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html)

```
Wp1 = RootReduce[Wp /. si -> 1];

lx = 13; Timing[pd = Plot[Wp1, {x, 0, lx},
   PlotRange -> {{0, lx}, {0.0225, .0275}},
   ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

```
Wd = D[Wp, x];
```

Prior to plotting, simplify the function using `RootReduce`

```
Wd1 = RootReduce[Wd /. si -> 1];

Timing[Plot[Wd1, {x, 0, lx},
  PlotRange -> {{0, lx}, {-0.002, .002}},
  ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

Comment: RootReduce divides by a 100 the execution time. Miraculous :)